# Which permissions to expect in oauth_third_party when tracking PayPal seller onboarding status

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working on integrating PayPal onboarding for sellers before payment. The developer documentation mentions that we can consider the seller successfully onboarded if the following conditions are true:

1. payments_receivable is true.
2. primary_email_confirmed is true.
3. oauth_third_party contains granted permissions.

However, I'm uncertain about what to expect within oauth_third_party, specifically regarding the list of scopes under "oauth_third_party".

If I am enabling features for the sellers such as [PAYMENT, REFUND, PARTNER_FEE, VAULT], which permissions should I expect to see in the response body?

This is the endpoint I am using:
`https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/customer/partners/{partner_id}/merchant-integrations/{merchant_id}`

Comment: seems to be a "test in PayPal sandbox and see" question